# Is there a good way to speed up this VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I have to run this code on a sheet of about 5000+ rows. At this point I could do it faster manually. I need to add a new row, carry a few values down from the previous row, create subtotals, and reshade wherever there is a change in column 'G'. This code will start in row 8 and only needs to be applied to cells E:X. Is there a better way to do this?

On further testing it seems the issue is that I'm having to add hundreds of rows individually. Is there a way to find all the rows where the value is not equal to the one above and add all rows en masse?

```
Sub subtotals()

'counter variables
cs = 8
c = 8


Do Until Range("E" & r) = ""


c = r
cs = r

'Do until Material Column does not equal material above
Do Until Range("g" & r) <> Range("g" & r + 1)
c = c + 1
r = r + 1
Loop

r = r + 1

Rows(r).Insert

'total label in SECTION
x = "e"
Range(x & r) = "Total"

x = "q"
Range(x & r).Formula = "=sum(" & x & cs & ":" & x & c & ")"

'rows to shade
Range("E" & r, "x" & r).Locked = True
Range("E" & r, "x" & r).Select

'shading
With Selection.Interior
.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
.TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Font
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
.TintAndShade = 0
.Bold = True
End With
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

r = r + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `Do Until Range("E" & r) = ""` throws an error because r is 0 and there is no cell `E0`. I guess you need to tell us the first row of your data (is it `8`?). Also, do confirm that you want this formatting to be done to only columns `E:X`, columns `A:D` not included.

Comment: Thank you, that would be good information to add. I had to delete some code to get this question in here. The first row of data starts in row 8 and the formatting only needs to be applied in columns A:D. The formula in 'Q' would also be applied to R:S & W:X, but I run this code on other similar workbooks and will need to be able to change those columns easily (hence defining x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Insert Subtotals

- Up to a thousand inserted rows this will behave i.e. it'll take a few seconds. After that, it might take forever.
- Try implementing `Application.Calculation` and `Application.ScreenUpdating` into your code. Its usage is pretty straightforward. It will speed up your code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertSubtotals()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1" ' adjust
    Const fRow As Long = 8 ' First Row
    Const tCol As String = "E" ' Total Column
    Const cCol As String = "G" ' Criteria (Search) Column
    Const fCol As String = "Q" ' Formula Column
    Const fCols As String = "E:X" ' Format Columns
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, tCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow < fRow Then Exit Sub ' no data

    Dim pRow As Long: pRow = lRow + 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim trg As Range ' Total Range
    Dim OldValue As Variant
    Dim NewValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim pFormula As String
    
    For r = pRow To fRow + 1 Step -1
        NewValue = ws.Cells(r - 1, cCol).Value
        If StrComp(CStr(NewValue), CStr(OldValue), vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            If pRow > r Then
                WriteFormula ws, r, pRow, fCol
                pRow = r
            End If
            ws.Rows(r).Insert
            If Not trg Is Nothing Then
                Set trg = Union(trg, ws.Cells(r, tCol))
            Else
                Set trg = ws.Cells(r, tCol)
            End If
            OldValue = NewValue
        End If
    Next r
    WriteFormula ws, fRow, pRow, fCol
     
    ' Write 'Total' in one go.
    trg.Value = "Total"
    
    ' Apply formatting in one go.
    With Intersect(trg.EntireRow, ws.Columns(fCols))
        .Locked = True
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
            .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Bold = True
        End With
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub WriteFormula( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal r As Long, _
        ByVal pRow As Long, _
        ByVal ColumnString As String)
    Dim pFormula As String
    pFormula = "=SUM(" & ColumnString & r & ":" & ColumnString & pRow - 1 & ")"
    ws.Cells(pRow, ColumnString).Formula = pFormula
End Sub
```

Comment: This is way faster. In three of the columns I'd also like to carry down the value from the previous cell. In addition to 'trg.value = "Total", I've added 'mrg.value = '. How would I make this reference the cell above?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? Do you mean the totals for `R`, `S`, and `W`?

Comment: If I added a column in row '10', I'd also like to carry the values from 'G9', 'H9', and 'I9'. Is there a way to do that using your same logic from the 'Total' column (where we add it all in one shot?)

Comment: Something like `Intersect(trg.EntireRow, ws.Columns("G")).Value = ws.Range("G9")`, but I thought the headers were in row `7`?

Comment: I want to indicate what material the subtotal is for. I think I can write a separate piece fairly easy for this. No worries, thank you far all your help!